# Как можно ускорить поиск данных в словаре Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, sqlite, инспекция-кода

У меня есть лист строк и словарь. Например:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
d = {
    "1": 
        {
            "ids": ["7612029690", "7612018248"], 
            "words": ["d", "o", "m"]
        },
    "2": 
        {
            "ids": ["7612018249", "7612029691"], 
            "words": ["a", "b", "c"]
        },
    ....
}
```

Мне надо найти такой элемент словаря `d`, в котором в ключе `"words"` наибольшее количество элементов из листа `a`. Ниже метод, в котором это вычисляется.

```
def find_best(a, d):
    result = {"words": [], "intersactions": 0}
    for v in d.values():
        i = len(list(set(a) & set(v["words"])))
        if i > result["intersactions"]:
            result = {"words": v, "intersactions": i}
    return result
```

Как можно ускорить поиск? Поможет ли в этом построение индекса данных? И будет ли работать код быстрее, если использовать базу данных и sqlite3?

Comment: У меня такое чувство, будто вы пытаетесь навелосипедить полнотекстовый поиск... Может, вам стоит поискать в интернете материалы на тему этого самого полнотекстового поиска?

Comment: Ну, find никогда и не являлся полнотекстовым поиском

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых можно один раз сделать список множеством в начале функции.
Во-вторых можно не преобразовывать в список результат пересечения множеств.
Хотя прирост будет очень мал даже на больших объемах данных.

```
def find_best(a, d):
    result = {"words": [], "intersactions": 0}
    a = set(a) # <---
    for v in d.values():
        i = len(a & set(v["words"])) # <---
        if i > result["intersactions"]:
            result = {"words": v, "intersactions": i}
    return result
```

Вероятно (проверить не на чем), будет небольшой прирост от замены сохранения в переменную и сравнения на функцию `max`:

```
def find_best(a, d):
    result = {"words": [], "intersactions": 0}
    a = set(a) # <---
    for v in d.values():
        result = {"words": v, "intersactions": max(len(a & set(v["words"])), result['intersactions'])}
    return result
```